# Qual é a diferença entre essas duas formas de chamar um método através de um evento no VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

Qual a diferença nessas duas maneiras de chamar um método no VueJS ? Lembrando que das duas formas funcionam.

Observem na linha onde o método é chamado pelo evento "click".

**1ª Forma:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    chamarAlert() {
      alert('Chamou')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="chamarAlert()">
    Chamar alert 
  </button>
</div>
```

**2ª Forma:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    chamarAlert() {
      alert('Chamou')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="() => chamarAlert()">
    Chamar alert 
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim há diferença entre as chamadas veja o exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ka3osrfu/ isso por conta de como as declarações de funções determinam o valor de `this`. Antes de escrever uma resposta tenho que verificar a relevância e as consequências do uso de diretivas como [`vue/no-arrow-functions-in-watch`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-arrow-functions-in-watch.html#vue-no-arrow-functions-in-watch) nos dois casos.

Answer (score -3):

Quando você usa o   `@click="() => chamarAlert()">`

Você tem a possibilidade de passar o evento para a função `@click="(event) => chamarAlert(event)">`

Mas nas versões mais nova do vue você pode passar o evento usando o **$event**

`@click="chamarAlert($event)">`